# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, vtiger

There is a weird problem with my server. I have a web application (vtiger CRM) locally and it works fine, it loads the neccessary data as it should (in the Email Manager module). The exact same copy is hosted on the server, and it gives the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
MailManager._mainui_callback
(anonymous function)
n
o.fireWith 
w 
d
```

Sometimes it just gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
```

Has this ever happened to anyone? Could there be something different in the server php.ini file which causes this?

Your help is much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: To give a more descriptive example I could copy and paste the actual code which is responsible for this but since the same code works locally, I am pretty sure this is a server issue. And that's the point of this question. However, this is the function which accepts a response parameter and sends it as an argument via `MailManager._mainui_callback` function:

```
                   function(response){

                        MailManager._mainui_callback(response);
                        progressIndicatorElement.progressIndicator({
                            'mode' : 'hide'
                        })
                        jQuery("#_folderprogress_").hide();
                        var timeOut = jQuery("#refresh_timeout").val();
                        if(timeOut != "" && timeOut !=0) {
                            setInterval(MailManager.updateMailFolders, timeOut);
                        }
                        // Update the seleted folders to highlight them.
                        var folderName = jQuery('#mm_selected_folder').val();
                        MailManager.updateSelectedFolder(folderName);
                    }
```

This is the callback function that does some stuff with the response:

```
       _mainui_callback: function(responseJSON){
            jQuery('#_mainfolderdiv_').html(responseJSON['result']['ui']);

            if (!responseJSON['result']['mailbox']) {
                MailManager.open_settings();
            }

            MailManager.triggerUI5Resize();
        }
```

What makes me wonder is, why does this work locally and not in the server?

Comment: This is a javascript error and it works locally.

Comment: It is also tagged with php because it is a server problem as it works locally. I just wanted to know what changes to make on the php.ini so that this will work also on the server.

Comment: [You may want to look here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How is that supposed to help me with my current problem?

Comment: It can help you give us more descriptive example of your problem, so we can help you.